# How to run a single list of stages in parallel on multiple platforms

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a series of stages involved in building and testing. I want to run these on multiple platforms in parallel. I cannot work out how to do this using the declarative syntax.

Based on the documentation for `parallel` and the examples I am trying to set a variable to the list of stages to run in each of two parallel stages, but it looks like you can't use variables in this way in the declarative fashion?

```
def stage_list = {
    stage('hello world') {
        steps {
            echo "hello world"
        }
    }
    stage('dump environment') {
        steps {
            echo "---- environment ----"
            sh "env | sort"
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('multi platform build') {
            parallel {
                stage ('Ubuntu') {
                    agent { label "Ubuntu" }
                    stages stage_list
                }
                stage ('CentOS') {
                    agent { label "CentOS" }
                    stages stage_list
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like it doesn't interpret the variable? Is there some way of doing this?

```
WorkflowScript: 22: Expected a block for stages @ line 22, column 6.
                    stages stage_list
```